# Delete table rows should not allow to delete last row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, tablerow

I have a table and I am deleting the table rows using the following script:

```
$("#ordertable tr input:checked").parents('tr').remove();
```

Then I am updating the table ids as follows:

```
function updateRowCount(){
  var table = document.getElementById("ordertable");
  var rowcountAfterDelete = document.getElementById("ordertable").rows.length;  
  for(var i=1;i<rowcountAfterDelete;i++) { 
    table.rows[i].id="row_"+i;
    table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML=i+"<input type='checkbox' id='chk_" + i + "'>";
    var j = i+1;
    $("#ordertable tr:nth-child("+j+")").find("td").eq(1).find("select").attr("id","pn_"+i);
    $("#ordertable tr:nth-child("+j+")").find("td").eq(2).find("input").attr("id","notes_"+i);
    $("#ordertable tr:nth-child("+j+")").find("td").eq(3).find("input").attr("id","qty_"+i);
    table.rows[i].cells[4].id = "pdctid_"+i;
  }
}
```

I need a condition in such a way that user can not allow to delete last row.

**I mean in deletion If user marked last row checkbox then I should get an alert.**

Comment: Do you mean "can't delete the last row" as in if there are 10 rows, they can delete any but the 10th (i.e. first to ninth), or that there must be at least one row in the table?

Comment: @RobG You are spot on buddy. Yah it should not allow to delete last row.

Comment: Try using, .is(":last-child"), $($("#ordertable tr").is(":last-child"), if it return true skip removing row

Comment: `$("#ordertable tr:not(last-child) input:checked").parents('tr').remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to not delete the last row with a checked checkbox. So you'd get the row to be deleted, then get the row with the last checked checkbox. If they're the same row, don't delete. Otherwise, delete.

The following is just an example of putting the above algorithm to the test. Of course there is much to improve to suit your circumstance.

E.g.

```js
function deleteRow(el) {

  // Get the row candidate for deletion
  var row = el.parentNode.parentNode;
  
  // Get last checked checkbox row, if there is one
  var table = row.parentNode.parentNode;
  var cbs = table.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
  var cbRow = cbs.length? cbs[cbs.length - 1].parentNode.parentNode : null;
  
  // If the row to be deleted is the same as the last checked checkbox row
  // don't delete it
  if (row === cbRow) {
    alert("Can't touch this...");
  
  // Otherwise, delete it
  } else {
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>0 <input type="checkbox">
    <td><button onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
  <tr>
    <td>1 <input type="checkbox">
    <td><button onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
  <tr>
    <td>2 <input type="checkbox">
    <td><button onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
</table>
```

Comment: that I know. I need to check whether the last row containing checkbox ticked or not during deletion!!

Comment: @Santhucool last row ever or just the last row containing a ticked checkbox? could you post an image of what you mean?

Comment: @Santhucool—now I'm confused. Do you want to only delete the last row if it's checkbox isn't checked? Anyway, there's enough here for you to answer your question.